# The question about a glvalue constant expression used in a context that requires a constant expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
constexpr int func2(int const& id){
    return id;
}
template<int v>
struct Test{

};
int main(){
   const int v = 0;
   Test<func2(v)> c;
}
```

Consider the above code,I just don't understand why the code is well-formed.My pointview is that the name `v` is used as a glvalue when evalute expression `func2`,becuase the parameter of `func2` is of reference type,the `v` need to be bound to the id-expression `id`.So we look at the requirement of a glvalue constant expression,here are quotes about that.

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints.

We ignore the case of prvalue,because here `v` is used as a glvalue.

#### An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression is:

> An entity is a permitted result of a constant expression if it is an object with **static storage duration** that is either not a temporary object or is a temporary object whose value satisfies the above constraints, or it is a function.

In my program portion,The `const int v = 0;` does not have **static storage duration**,it just has automatic storage duration.So when evaluting the expression `func2(v)` to determine whether it is a constant expression,Firstly,the `v` must be a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression,therefore,why the program is well-formed here?If I lose any important quote,Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

> We ignore the case of prvalue, because here v is used as a glvalue

Is it though? This is an example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression):

```
void test() {
    static const int a = std::random_device{}();
    constexpr const int& ra = a; // OK: a is a glvalue constant expression
    constexpr int ia = a; // Error: a is not a prvalue constant expression

    const int b = 42;
    constexpr const int& rb = b; // Error: b is not a glvalue constant expression
    constexpr int ib = b; // OK: b is a prvalue constant expression
}
```

And yes, `const int b = 42` is rather weird here because technically speaking, you can bind `b` to `const int&`, `const_cast` the `const` away and assign a runtime value to it. However, considering what is an [integral constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) and [what are the requirements of a `const` object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) it makes perfect sense:

> Integral constant expression is an expression of integral or unscoped
>   enumeration type implicitly converted to a prvalue, where the
>   converted expression is a core constant expression. If an expression
>   of class type is used where an integral constant expression is
>   expected, the expression is contextually implicitly converted to an
>   integral or unscoped enumeration type.

Variable `b` sure does look like something you could implicitly convert to a prvalue constant expression because it basically serves as an alias for literal `42` in this context and integer literals are prvalues by definition.

Now for the problematic part - this:

> const object - an object whose type is const-qualified, or a
>   non-mutable subobject of a const object. Such object cannot be
>   modified: attempt to do so directly is a compile-time error, and
>   attempt to do so indirectly (e.g., by modifying the const object
>   through a reference or pointer to non-const type) results in undefined
>   behavior.

And:

> A core constant expression is any expression whose evaluation would
>   not evaluate any one of the following:
>
> ...
>
> an expression whose evaluation leads to any form of core language
>   undefined behavior (including signed integer overflow, division by
>   zero, pointer arithmetic outside array bounds, etc). Whether standard
>   library undefined behavior is detected is unspecified.

Means that as soon as you start doing funny things with that `b`, you can expect anything to happen. For example, this is what I tried doing to your code in latest MSVC with all standard-conformance options switched on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

constexpr int func2(int const& id) {
    return id;
}

template<int v>
struct Test {

    long array[v];

};

int main() {

    const int v = 0;
    const int& ref = v;

    const_cast<int&>(ref) = std::random_device()() % std::numeric_limits<int>::max();


    Test<func2(v)> c;

    return 0;

}
```

With language extensions turned on I got a [C4200: nonstandard extension used : zero-sized array in struct/union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-levels-2-and-4-c4200?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C4200)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019) warning. After switching them off, the program wouldn't compile. And when I deleted the `array` part from the struct it started compiling again.

Comment: In your example,For `constexpr const int& ra = a; `,because a is a object with static storage duration,For `constexpr int ia = a;`,becuase there is a l-to-v conversion performed on `a` and a is not initialized by a constant expression,so it's ill-formed.

Comment: *"`const int b = 42` is rather weird here because technically speaking, you can bind `b` to `const int&`, `const_cast` the `const` away and assign a runtime value to it". Modifying const object is undefined behavior, so no, you cannot do that.

Comment: @Jarod42 Undefined behavior implies inability to predict the results of something, not inability to do something.

Comment: You can do stuff not allowed and so have UB or have ill-formed program, but what is te point? I don't see the point of your answer.

Answer (score -2):

I try to answer this question.why the `func2(v)` is a constant expression,Becuase For expression func2(v),when evaluting this postfix-expression,there's no requirement that `v` must be a glvalue constant expression in the list of "would evaluate one of the following expressions:",Even,these rules does not mandate that the one expression within a potentially core constant expression would be a glvalue constant expression,only require the expression does not violate the listed requirement.So let's continue,When initialization of the parameter,It's another rule here:

> A full-expression is:
>
> > - [...]
> > - an **init-declarator** or a mem-initializer, including the constituent expressions of the initializer

So,when evalute this full-expression,it only does not violate these listed condition,then the `func2(v)` would be evaluted as a constant expression,So let's look at these rules:

> an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
> > - it is initialized with a constant expression or,
> > - its lifetime began within the evaluation of e;

For id-expression `id`,its preceding initialization is the corresponding argument,Because of this rule:

> When a function is called, each parameter ([dcl.fct]) shall be initialized ([dcl.init], [class.copy], [class.ctor]) with its corresponding argument.

So,the first condition is true.And "it is initialized with a constant expression" is false,the condition "its lifetime began within the evaluation of e" is true.In conlusion,the expression `func2(v)` indeed a constant expression