# How to understand the sentence its lifetime began within the evaluation of e

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
int main(){
  int v = 0;
  int const& rf = v;
}
```

To determine whether the expression `int const& rf = v;` is a core constant expression,it need to undergo these quotes:

> an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either:
>
> > - it is initialized with a constant expression or
> > - its lifetime began within the evaluation of e;

when evalute expression `int const& rf = v;`,the expression `rf` of reference type will be evaluted.For this id-expression,it has a preceding initialization,however `v` is not a constant expression.Does `rf`'s lifetime began within the evaluation of `int const& rf = v;`,I just don't know how to understand `within`.I only find the lifetime rule about reference is here:

> The lifetime of a reference begins when its initialization is **complete**. The lifetime of a reference ends as if it were a scalar object.

So,Is this a situation of `its lifetime began within the evaluation of e;`,if it's not,how to understand the keyword `within` here?

Comment: Which standard version are you referencing?

Comment: `int const& rf = v;` is a declaration, not an expression. Do you mean to ask whether the subsequent expression `rf` would be a core constant expression?

Comment: (if so, it isn't because it names a reference whose lifetime had already started before evaluation of the expression)

Comment: @NicolBolas  version of n4659

Comment: @M.M Maybe I list a wrong example,I just want to know how to understand its lifetime began **within** the evaluation of e.

Comment: It is the normal english word "within" .  If its lifetime had not started before `e`'s evaluation started,  and does started before `e`'s evaluation finishes, then its lifetime would begin within the evaluation of `e`

Comment: @M.M you mean the rule is for **expression**,in my example,`int const& rf = v;`,it's just a  declaration not **expression**,so the rule does not mandate for it?Another example is about function's parameter,if `int const& rf` is a function's parameter,Does the parameter's lifetime begin within the expression `function`?or,for `function(a)`,it's also a declaration for it's paramter as if  int const& rf = a?

Comment: @jackX: Core constant expressions are, first and foremost, *expressions*. The definition of a variable is not a core constant expression.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks,if it  occurs in invocation of function,Does the parameter of reference type bind to a argument belong to a expression,or It still a declaration?

Comment: Why the quote you provided is relevant to your example? The id-expression here _doesn't_ refer to a reference: the id-expression `v` is not a reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [beginning of that series of statements](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#const-2) is:

> An expression `e` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:

`int const& rf = v;` is a declaration, not an expression. Therefore, asking whether it is a core constant expression makes no sense. You can ask where `v` is a core constant expression. You can ask whether some *usage* of `rf` is a core constant expression.

But you can't ask if a declaration is a core constant expression.

---

As for how to read "within", you read it as in plain English. `e` is an expression, and the above quoted section talks about its evaluation. "Within its evaulation" would be the sequence of things that happen during its evaluation.

Comment: For example,`constexpr int function(int const& rf){return rf;}    const int value = 0;function(value);`,For expression `function(value)`,During the evaluation of expression `function(value)`,the parameter `int const& rf` need to bind to argument `value`,Firstly Is the parameter initialization a expression or a declaration?Second,if it is a expression,Is the lifetime of `rf` begin within evaluation of expression `function(value)`?

Comment: What you're saying seems so confused that I'm having trouble deciding how to respond. I guess my biggest question is what is it that you're *actually* trying to figure out here? What are you trying to understand about these hypothetical `rf`s that you keep proposing? What are you doing with them where their nature as a core constant expression or lack thereof is relevant? And why do you keep trying to equate the act of creating a variable with an expression?

Comment: @NicoBolas I think what I want to understand is the essence of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61926165/the-question-about-a-glvalue-constant-expression-used-in-a-context-that-requires/61926911#61926911),In other words,Is a initialization of a parameter a expression or declaration?

Comment: @jackX: It's neither. The initialization of a parameter from an argument is part of the process of calling a function.

Comment: "Neither" means it's not a expression,So ,when evaluate a function call whether it is a constant expression,the initialization of each parameter is not considered,Right?

Comment: @jackX: What do you mean by "considered"? Initialization of parameters by arguments is not an optional part of a function call expression. It is a thing that happens during evaluating that expression. The things that happen when you call a function are not necessarily expressions *themselves*, but that doesn't mean that they aren't "considered" to be part of the expression's evaluation.

Comment: I think you have misunderstand what I mean,I mean when determine whether a expression of function call is a constant expression,For example,`function(value)`,"An expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions".Here `e` is  `function(value)`,thereof,Would the initialization of a parmeter be taken as "evaluate one of the following expressions"?

Comment: @jackX No, the initialization of the parameter is not evaluating an expression. But item (2.11) "an _id-expression_ that refers to..." does apply to the expression `rf` in the definition of `function`. Since the lifetime of the reference began within the evaluation of `function(value)`, that alone won't stop `function(value)` from being a core constant expression.

Comment: @aschepler The initialization of the parameter indeed a part of full-expression and its evaluation be covered in the sentence "full-expression shall be a constant-expression",it will cover any evaluation, such as type converting, if you change the parameter to a non-literal class type, then that would be not a constant-expression.